# How to Insert text into column in mysql under same useraccount

Tags: c#, mysql

In my code,the program is supposed to check to see if the user has an account and to see if the user has a secondarily group of 7. If those are true, I want to then insert the HWID of the computer into the members_hwid field under the same account. I do not know how to do all of this in 1 command so I wrote another function to insert the hwid into the name of the account. The problem is it creates a different account and then puts the hwid for the fake account... How can I fix this to where it puts the hwid under the correct account? Below is my current running code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string server = "207.244.70.217";
    string database = "nextgene_NGH";
    string uid = "EXAMPLEUID";
    string password = "EXAMPLEPASSWORD";
    string ssl = "None";
    string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";  
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE name = @name AND mgroup_others = 7;", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
    var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    try
    {
        if (!(hashedPassword is null && !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword)))
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.username = maskedTextBox1.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.password = maskedTextBox2.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            var vip = new vipform();
            vip.Show();
            HM();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ISSUE IS: " + ex);
        //MessageBox.Show("Either Login information is Incorrect or You are not VIP.");               
    }

    CHECKHWID();
}
```

When this finishes executing, it then calls the CHECKHWID function, which is this:

```cs
public void CHECKHWID()
{
    try
    {
        string server = "207.244.70.217";
        string database = "nextgene_NGH";
        string uid = "EXAMPLEUID";
        string password = "EXAMPLEPASSWORD";
        string ssl = "None";
        string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO core_members(name, member_hwid) VALUES (@name, @hwid)", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
        var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ISSUE IS: " + ex);        
    }
}
```

Finally, when I check the database after it executes CHECKHWID, I see that it added another user named XXX with the HWID but it did not add the HWID to the original user or name from the button1_click. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *`I want to then insert the HWID of the computer into the members_hwid field under the same account.`* You want to *UPDATE* the existing row with the ID, not INSERT

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I have updated it to this:  ***` using var command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE core_members SET name = @name WHERE member_hwid = @hwid", connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
                var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();`***. It now does nothing in the table.

Comment: that looks completely backwards if you want to INSERT the ID for a given name.  Suggested reading: [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)  also a good SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In the WHERE clause of your SQL query try to use the username instead of hwid.

Hint: SET member_hwid = @hwid WHERE name = @name